# E890 Trailing char after ']' - vim/neovim regex

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, neovim

When I reload my syntax file I receive this error:

```
E890: trailing char after ']': /v(.)@<=w+[nrs]/
```

Here's the line it's bugging out on, does anyone see why this doesn't work?

```
syntax keyword langMethod /\v(\.)\@<=\w+[]/
```

Comment: `[]` is an empty collection. Why do you have that in your pattern?

Comment: I apologize I copied the commented out version of my regex, the actual one has `[\r\n\s]` in the collection.

Comment: Then the error message should be sufficient: you need to escape the backslashes. Try `[\\r\\n\\s]`.

Comment: Same error message as before, tho now the parsed regex looks as so: `/v(.)@<=w+\r\n\s]/` Shouldn't there be a `[` after `w+`?

Comment: Does Neovim support patterns with `syn keyword`? I think Vim doesn't - all it allows is an optional tail (or abbreviation).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've figured it out. It has to do with your "very magic" option. You have a lookbehind: `(\.)\@<=`. However, in very magic mode you are not supposed to escape the `@` in a lookaround.

On a slightly unrelated note, You have a `\s` in your character class `[]`. You can't use shortcuts in character classes. (@muru pointed out that what you're looking for here with this character class is `\_s` which matches whitespace and newlines.) So the final expression I've come up with is the following:

```
/\v(\.)@<=\w+\_s/
```

See if that works for you.

It is my personal preference never to use the `\v` flag for this very reason. Too many exceptions to remember. I just like to use the default regex and learn one set of rules. :P

Comment: To match newlines with `\s`: [`\_s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C_s).